# Need help understanding puppeteer node async functions

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Hey I guys I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior of my puppeteer code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const sleep = require("sleep");

const runPuppeteer = () => {
  puppeteer
    .launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    })
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 800 });
      await page.goto("https://www.chevrolet.co.kr/chevy/as.gm?");

      dataHolder = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 84; i++) {
        inventoryTransferTableTags = await page.$$(".list");
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // **** Loop #1 ****
          console.log(i);
          i = inventoryTransferTableTags[i];
        }
        console.log("--------------");
        sleep.sleep(3);
      }
    });
};

runPuppeteer();
```

From loop #1, I was expecting to to see
console.log(i) -> 0,1,2,3,4 but I get an output of

0

--------------

it seems that
i = inventoryTransferTableTags[i]

has an async issue, but I have no idea how to deal with it - should I make a promise for this single line?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're successfully logging the value of `i` on the first iteration of the loop:

```
console.log(i);
```

But look at what you do immediately afterward:

```
i = inventoryTransferTableTags[i];
```

So what's the value of `i` now?  Clearly, whatever it is, `i < 5` is now `false` because the loop terminates and your next operation is performed:

```
console.log("--------------");
```

When you modify the loop iterator value, you can terminate the loop.